# How to combine \ifdefstring (etoolbox) with \multicolumn

Tags: tables, etoolbox

I need to make  tabulars with either norwegian or english column heading above the numbers. I have defined a command, `\ReportLanguage`, that can be set to either of two values, "`no`" for norwegian, and "`en`" for english. This language choise command is then combined with the etoolbox function `\ifdefstring` to make a switch between norwegian and english header text above the tabular content. This language switch function is shown below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ReportLanguage}{en}
% two alternative values for \ReportLanguage: 
% "no" for norwegian and "en" for english

    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
          \ifdefstring{\ReportLanguage}{no}%
              {Dybde & temperatur & Salinitet  \\}
              {Depth & temperature  & Salinity  \\}                           
                \midrule
                100 & 10 & 32 \\
                150 & 7  & 33 \\            
                180 & 4  & 35 \\
                \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

This works fine for either two values of the \ReportLanguage variable, and gives the following compiled result when \ReportLanguage is set to the value "en".

[image]

However, I would like to have a common heading above the two first headings, the "Depth" and "temperature" headings. I have tried to use the `\multicolumn` function inside the `\ifdefstring` language switch function, but I get an error message. The code looks as this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ReportLanguage}{no}
% two alternative values for \ReportLanguage: 
% "no" for norwegian and "en" for english

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \ifdefstring{\ReportLanguage}{no}%
          {\multicolumn{2}{c}{Utslippspunkt} & Salinitet  \\       
             Dybde & temperatur                &             \\}
          {\multicolumn{2}{c}{Release point}  & Salinity  \\                           
            Depth & temperature                &            \\}
            \midrule
            100 & 10 & 32 \\
            150 & 7  & 33 \\            
            180 & 4  & 35 \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and the error message looks as this:

[image]

What is wrong with my code? I will appreciate help on this topic, thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for recognizing where exactly the error lies and for a very good minimal example!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `\ifdefstring` is not *expandable*, therefore it cannot be used at this place of a table. You can overcome this by using the low-level `\ifx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ReportLanguage}{no}
% two alternative values for \ReportLanguage: 
% "no" for norwegian and "en" for english
\newcommand{\NorwegianLanguage}{no}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \ifx\ReportLanguage\NorwegianLanguage
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Utslippspunkt} & Salinitet  \\       
             Dybde & temperatur                &             \\
      \else
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Release point}  & Salinity  \\                           
            Depth & temperature                &            \\
      \fi
            \midrule
            100 & 10 & 32 \\
            150 & 7  & 33 \\            
            180 & 4  & 35 \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

At a beginning of a table cell/line, LaTeX looks for things like `\multicolumn`, `\hline` etc. When you put something non-expandable there, LaTeX simply stops looking for these things. And if they are found later (like your `\multicolumn`), LaTeX is confused and throws an error.

Just a remark: I think you want `twoside` instead of `twosided` (maybe both work, I dunno, I always use the first one).

---

If you don't want to define `\NorwegianLanguage`, you can do this (**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ReportLanguage}{no}
% two alternative values for \ReportLanguage: 
% "no" for norwegian and "en" for english

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \expandafter\ifx\csname\ReportLanguage LANGUAGE\endcsname\noLANGUAGE
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Utslippspunkt} & Salinitet  \\       
             Dybde & temperatur                &             \\
      \else
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Release point}  & Salinity  \\                           
            Depth & temperature                &            \\
      \fi
            \midrule
            100 & 10 & 32 \\
            150 & 7  & 33 \\            
            180 & 4  & 35 \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But, could your solution work without the new command  \NorwegianLanguage? could "\ifx\ReportLanguage\NorwegianLanguage" be exchanged with "\ifx\ReportLanguage no" ?

Comment: It can, but it's a very dirty trick, I'll update in a minute

Comment: That *is* a very dirty trick. One might expect the `\ifx` test to be always true (because the compared macros `\enLANGUAGE` and `\noLANGUAGE` are both undefined) or always false (because the `\csname...\endcsname` of an undefined macro is `\relax`). But TeX's treatment of `\expandafter\ifx\csname...` is very strange (to me).   Also odd is `\expandafter\ifx\noexpand\cmd\cmd`, which is true for unexpandable commands and false for expandable ones!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a more user-friendly approach: you issue a `\TableHeader` command that contains a key-value list of the headers you want for the next table, then in the table you place `\UseTableHeader`.

In the example I switch language (which probably you don't want to do in a real document) just to show the result; notice that the values given as argument to `\TableHeader` survive until another `\TableHeader` is issued again.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{espentable}{no}{\def\espen@header@no{#1}}
\define@key{espentable}{en}{\def\espen@header@en{#1}}

\newcommand{\TableHeader}[1]{%
  \setkeys{espentable}{#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\UseTableHeader}{\@nameuse{espen@header@\espen@language}}

% two alternative values for \ReportLanguage: 
% "no" for norwegian and "en" for english
\newcommand{\ReportLanguage}[1]{\def\espen@language{#1}}
\def\espen@language{en}% default
\makeatother

\ReportLanguage{no}

\begin{document}

Norsk:

\TableHeader{
  no={\multicolumn{2}{c}{Utslippspunkt} & Salinitet \\
      Dybde & temperatur                &           \\},
  en={\multicolumn{2}{c}{Release point}  & Salinity \\                           
      Depth & temperature                &          \\}
}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\UseTableHeader
\midrule
100 & 10 & 32 \\
150 & 7  & 33 \\            
180 & 4  & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

English:

\ReportLanguage{en}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\UseTableHeader
\midrule
100 & 10 & 32 \\
150 & 7  & 33 \\            
180 & 4  & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This has the advantage that it's easily extendable to more than two languages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I will dive into your solution and study it in detail : )